# How to capture hide/restore event, during click at taskbar

Tags: c++, winapi

I'd like to capture click-event at taskbar button of the application. How to do that?

Comment: yes, but I don't find a way how to do that. Thats why I put a message at stackoverflow

Comment: Pretty much all your questions seem to be one-line "how do I do X?" "how do I do Y?" :(

Comment: Since when does SO require long questions?  His one-liner question is complete and valid (and, oddly enough, it appears in the first page of results in my own Google search).  Stop with the condescending alpha-geek baloney.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking the taskbar button will cause Windows to send a WM_ACTIVATEAPP message to the program, with a param that lets you know if it is being activated or deactivated.  Handle this message to be notified.  There will also be a later WM_SHOWWINDOW message with a SW_RESTORE or SW_MINIMIZE parameter.

The more important question is "Why?"  If by capturing this click the program is going to do anything other than behave like a normal Windows application (Activate if inactive, inactivate if active) then the user will be surprised.  It is rarely a good idea to surprise the user with non-standard behavior for managing application windows.  If instead, you are using this capture to control internal state in the application, without changing how the app activates and deactivates, these WM_... messages are how it can be done.